# Aggregate R sum

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I'm writting my first 
program in R and as a newbie I'm having some troubles, hope you can help me.

I've got a data frame like this:

```
> v1<-c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4)
> v2<-c(13,5,15,1,2,7,4)
> v3<-c(0,3,6,13,8,23,5)
> v4<-c(26,25,11,2,8,1,0)
> datos<-data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)
> names(datos)<-c("Position","a1","a2","a3")

> datos
  posicion a1 a2 a3
1        1 13  0 26
2        1  5  3 25
3        2 15  6 11
4        3  1 13  2
5        3  2  8  8
6        3  7 23  1
7        4  4  5  0
```

What I need is to sum the data in `a1`, `a2` and `a3` (in my real case from `a1` to `a51`) grouped by `Position`. I'm trying with the function `aggregate()` but it only works for means, not for sums and I don't know why.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward with the `plyr` library.

```
library("plyr")
ddply(datos, .(Position), colwise(sum))
```

If you have additional non-numeric columns that shouldn't be averaged, you can use

```
ddply(datos, .(Position), numcolwise(sum))
```

Comment: Hi Brian, I've made a proof and it seems to be what I need. However I need to check some things with my real data. I'll let you know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I've checked it and it's just what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 16):

You need to tell the aggregate function to use sum, as the default is for it to get the mean of each category.  For example:

```
aggregate(datos[,c("a1","a2","a3")], by=list(datos$Position), "sum")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ag_df <-- aggregate(.~Position,data=datos,sum)
```

should give you a data frame containing the sums of the "a" values for each of the positions. The trick here is the **.** in the formula represents a list of all the "non-grouping" variables in the formula.

Note that you can get much the same result with:

```
sumdf <- rowsum(datos,datos$Position,na.rm=T)
```

Except that includes the sums of the positions as well!

If you DON'T want all non-group columns aggregated, you can use cbind as in:

```
sumdf1 <- aggregate(cbind(a1,a3)~datos$Position,datos,sum)
```

That sums only the a1 and a3 columns.