# Collapse data frame, adding values for factor

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aggregate R sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615922/aggregate-r-sum)

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
  sample value
1      a     1
2      a     2
3      b     3
4      b     4
5      b     5
6      c     6
```

I need to collapse the data frame over the levels of `sample` (may be a character vector or a factor), adding all the `value`s, so my resulting data frame looks like this:

```
  sample sum
1      a   3
2      b  12
3      c   6
```

It's Monday morning, and all I can think of is writing a complicated `for` loop. How might I vectorize this using apply, plyr, etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to load a package:

```
df <- read.table(text="  sample value
1      a     1
2      a     2
3      b     3
4      b     4
5      b     5
6      c     6",header=TRUE)

aggregate(df$value,by=list(sample=df$sample),sum)

  sample  x
1      a  3
2      b 12
3      c  6
```

Or if you prefer formula syntax:

```
aggregate(value ~ sample, df, sum)

  sample value
1      a     3
2      b    12
3      c     6
```

Answer (score 4):

I like cast, for these types of problems because it's quick and intuitive:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(your_df, sample ~ ., sum) # or just cast with the original reshape
```

I also like summarize, for this type of question.

```
library(plyr) 
ddply(df,.(sample),summarise, sum=sum(value))
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Upvoted because this works on my simple example, but when my data frame has many other columns, the code above returns an error "undefined columns selected".

Comment: Hard to diagnose without seeing at the very least the str() of your data. But you could always subset and cast `dcast(your_df[1:2], sample ~ .,sum)`

Comment: Small error in the ddply/summarise code. Should be: `ddply(df,.(sample),summarise, sum=sum(value))` which might fix the error you are seeing.

Comment: Woah, "Community" just updated that automatically based on your comment. Pretty cool beans.

Comment: Actually, that was me before I logged in. But when I logged in, the edit was not showing up, so I commented... I'm not sure I like that an unlogged user can update an answer like that... did you have to approve it?

Comment: I would have been really impressed if that was an automatic edit!

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of sharing, you can also use the `sqldf` and `data.table` packages quite easily:

Your data:

```
df <- read.table(text="  sample value
1      a     1
2      a     2
3      b     3
4      b     4
5      b     5
6      c     6",header=TRUE)
```

The `sqldf` alternative:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select sample, sum(value) `value` from df group by sample")
#   sample value
# 1      a     3
# 2      b    12
# 3      c     6
```

The `data.table` alternative:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key="sample")
DT[, list(value = sum(value)), by=key(DT)]
#    sample value
# 1:      a     3
# 2:      b    12
# 3:      c     6
```

Comment: +1 for sqldf, very useful if you already know SQL.

Answer (score 3):

The "classic" R command is ***tapply***

```
n <- 17; fac <- factor(rep(1:3, length = n), levels = 1:5)
df=data.frame(target=1:n, factor=fac)
with(df, tapply(target, fac, sum))
```

***by*** and ***aggregate*** both work but the input output as lists or ***by*** objects is daft. Also ***ddply*** from ***plyr*** will work but is somewhat less clear syntactically although it comes into its own for more complicated examples.

Answer (score 1):

One solution using R base function is

```
aggregate(x = df$value, by = list(df$sample), FUN = sum)
```

You can also do it with `ddply` from plyr package

```
ddply(df,.(sample),numcolwise(sum))
```

Here `df` is your data.frame