# Matching and Adding Factor Counts in R Data Frames

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

My question stems out of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280277/adding-counts-of-a-factor-to-a-dataframe) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567212/collapse-data-frame-adding-values-for-factor) question asked previously and sufficiently different from them I think. Imagine that I have a minimal dataset (bird) where every row represents an observation of birds at a given time and place as follows:

```
id,obs,country
A,4,USA
B,3,CAN
A,5,USA
C,4,MEX
C,1,USA
A,3,CAN
D,1,null
```

What I ideally want is a conversion of this dataset into a form like this removing the nulls from the dataset:

```
id,tot_obs,country_tot
A,12,2
B,3,1
C,5,2
```

I know that I can get a count of factors using:

```
table(bird$country)
```

but, is there a smarter, perhaps, one line way of removing the nulls, adding up the total counts, finding the counts of the countries and then reconfiguring them into this form? If there is a package which does this, then I am open to that suggestion as well. Thanks !

Comment: Shouldn't the `tot_obs` for first row be 12?

Comment: Apologies. It was a typo. I have edited it now.

Comment: Shion, yes, in that case, the answer below should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load data with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`:

```
df <- read.csv(header=TRUE, text="id,obs,country
A,4,USA
B,3,CAN
A,5,USA
C,4,MEX
C,1,USA
A,3,CAN
D,1,null", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# check to see if columns are factors
sapply(df, class)
#          id         obs     country 
# "character"   "integer" "character"
```

Remove all rows with `country = null`

```
df <- df[df$country != "null", ]
```

Then you can use `plyr` package with `summarise` to get the desired result as follows:

```
ddply(df, .(id), summarise, tot_obs=sum(obs), tot_country=length(unique(country)))
#   id tot_obs tot_country
# 1  A      12           2
# 2  B       3           1
# 3  C       5           2
```

Comment: I tried out the exact code as above. It gave me an error: `Error in Summary.factor(c(45L, 3L, 165L, 3L, 165L, 3L, 70L, 165L, 165L,  : 
  sum not meaningful for factors`

Comment: yes. make sure your columns are not factors. load your csv file with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` if need be.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you so much for your help. It all works well now.