# How to group date in R?

Tags: r

I have this csv data

```
Date                       Kilometer
2015-01-01 15:56:00          1
2015-01-01 17:40:00          2
2015-01-02 14:38:00          4
2015-01-02 14:45:00          3
```

And would like to group date and sum kilometer like that

```
Date                       Kilometer
2015-01-01                   3
2015-01-02                   7
```

Comment: Did you do any google search? This seems like such a basic question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615922/aggregate-r-sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using `dplyr` and `lubridate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Date = lubridate::date(Date)) %>% summarise(Kilometer=sum(Kilometer)) 


        Date Kilometer
      (date)     (int)
1 2015-01-01         3
2 2015-01-02         7
```

Comment: Error in function %<% ?

Comment: you have to have the library 'dplyr` loaded - also the function is written `%>%` - note the direction of the '>'

Comment: Sorry it is %>%, mistake
And will load dplyr now!

Comment: Not working , and unfortunately its not even giving any comment back, it just keep loading for ever while its just a mini data frame

Comment: do you have both packages - 'dplyr' and 'lubridate' loaded?

Comment: Absolutely, downloaded and loaded !

Comment: If all dates are in the same format as above it should work fine. How many rows  is the dataframe?

Comment: Okay, after waiting for a while it worked :) thanks a lot

Comment: @jalapic I've never used lubridate before, but I'm keen to learn more about time series data, since I often come up with issues. Any reason to use lubridate here instead of base as.Date ? Does it do this conversion differently?

Comment: `as.Date` is fine but like all programming languages dates can be a pain.  The `lubridate` package has a lot of easy to use functions. In this case it actually makes sensible guesses as to the format of the date without one having to specify the exact format for instance.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df)[, .(Kilometer = sum(Kilometer)) , .(Date=date(Date))]
```